# TextChangedListener Crashes on Me

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, textwatcher

I'm trying to only enable a button after every field in the form is populated. To that end I'm using a TextWatcher, but I keep getting an error.

Could it have to do with my contentView being activity_add_grade while my buttons and fields are in my fragment_add_grade xml? I'm new to this and tbh I don't fully understand why both xml files are auto-generated by ADT.

Code:

```
public class AddClass extends ActionBarActivity {

int baseYear=2005;
int thisYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

private EditText editText1;
private EditText editText2;

public TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher(){

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        checkFieldsForEmptyValues();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_grade);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCredit);

    // Program aborts as soon as I try to add the listener to editText1
    editText1.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    editText2.addTextChangedListener(watcher);

}
```

And my LogCat:

```
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961): Process: com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro, PID: 1961
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro/com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro.AddClass}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro.AddClass.onCreate(AddClass.java:63)
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-30 18:23:44.963: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Might be that your layout doesn't contain the id. Can you please add layout?

Answer (score 1):

Your activity_add_grade does not contain EditText with id editTitle

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
```

Looks like the findViewById method could not find an element with this id, so it returned `null`.

That is why later there is a **NullPointerException** thrown at this line:

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

==> add an id attribute `editTitle` to your EditText inside the layout `activity_add_grade`

Comment: When I created my AddGrade (later changed to AddClass) class, Eclipse automatically gave me activity_add_grade and fragment_add_grade XML files. I did my UI design (text fields, buttons) in fragment_add_grade, in accordance with android.com's tutorial. In other words, all of my UI is in fragment_add_grade, so moving my editTitle to activity_add_grade would mean real restructuring.

Comment: Also, I have another method in my AddClass class which accesses editTitle. Why doesn't it have trouble accessing it?

'public void createNewClass(View v) {
  EditText titleTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTitle);'

Comment: If you use the Activity's findViewById method than it will look inside the layout that you have previously set as the content view. If you use a fragment then you should inflate the fragment's layout in your Fragment and look up your EditText in the fragment's layout.